# How do I create a multidimensional lambda function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the code shown below but doesn't work...

For example, I want to put

```
X=[2,2,2]
```

then

```
S(X)=sum([4,4,4]+[1,1,1])=15

S=lamda X:sum(X**2+np.ones(3))
S(2*np.ones(3))
```

Comment: What error or unexpected result do you get?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your only problem is that you misspelled `lambda`

Comment: After your change it is not clear what the problem is. Could you specify what is not working?

Comment: Sorry, the mistake is just a typo. It should be lambda.

Comment: That's fine but what is the problem then? The code that you posted works well

Comment: If creating a `lambda` is tricky, use a regular function definition instead.  There's not virtue in use lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `lamda` with `lambda`.

```
X=[2,2,2]
S=lambda X:sum(X**2+np.ones(3))
print S(2*np.ones(3))
```

Output:

```
15.0
```

*I edited your question because I thought it was a typo but the change was rejected. I agree that the typo is the only problem so I am submitting this as an answer.*

Comment: You should just flag it as off-topic because it's just a typo.